# "Extrude poly ribbon" (ctrl+click) not working for me

Tags: topology, extrude, dynamic-topology

So I've been following this blender tutorial and have just created a head using Dyntopo.  I am now learning how to finish it with retopo.  I started out by turning on snap during transform (snap element: edges, snap target: active), and positioned a small plane the head.  The tutorial then went on to explain how to "extrude a poly ribbon" by selecting an edge of the plane and extruding it by pressing control and clicking, as shown below:

[image: poly ribbon]

When I try to do this, however, it does not seem to work.  It just outlines the head in orange, as shown:

[image: my head]

What should I try doing differently to make this work for me? If it matters, I am using a mac.

Comment: The another object might be outlined if you pressed Ctrl with right click.. while for extruding should be Ctrl + left click (or E as usual).

Comment: @MrZak Sorry for the late response, but thanks! This worked for me--I was just clicking with the wrong mouse button.  Silly me.

Answer (score 1):

Mac: If the answers above don't work for you, try: <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>⌘ Cmd</kbd><kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd>

In order for <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>⌘ Cmd</kbd><kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd> to work, you must have "Emulate 3 Button Mouse" checked.

To do this: *File* > *User Preferences* > *Input* tab > check *Emulate 3 Button Mouse* box

Comment: @22melloja (For the edit) Shortcut command should only have the first letter capitalized and don't need a "+" symbol. Let's keep it conform with the Blender user Preferences. Click is also not as accurate as LMB (left mouse button) or RMB. See [this](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/388/30849) post for a useful script to insert keyboad tags.